# Triggering click event of parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a issue where the .click from the div where my cancel button is nested in triggers when I click the button. This causes both the slideUp and slideDown to trigger at the same time, which results in the div staying visible. I've tried adding a state to prevent the div from sliding down again, but this does not have the desired effect.

```
$(add).click(function () {
 var inputDiv = Polymer.dom(root_root).querySelector("#inputDiv");
 if(state == 0){
   $(inputDiv).slideDown(300);
  }
 state = 1;
});
 $(cancel).click(function () {
  var inputDiv = Polymer.dom(root_root).querySelector("#inputDiv");
  $(inputDiv).slideUp(300);
  state = 0;
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kkdoneaj/2/

Does anyone know how to work around this issue?

Comment: Post the HTML code, please.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Event.stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) to stop the click from [bubbling](https://www.sitepoint.com/event-bubbling-javascript/) from the `#cancel` button to the parent `#add` div:

```
$("#cancel").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    ...
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kkdoneaj/3/

Answer (score 0):

you should put [`stop`](https://api.jquery.com/stop/)

> Stop the currently-running animation on the matched elements.

```
$(add).click(function () {
  var inputDiv = Polymer.dom(root_root).querySelector("#inputDiv");
  $(inputDiv).stop().slideDown(300);
});
$("#cancel").click(function (e) {
  var inputDiv = Polymer.dom(root_root).querySelector("#inputDiv");
  $(inputDiv).stop().slideUp(300);
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, sadly doing this locks the div in the down position.

Comment: @Michelindoll I do not understand what you mean

Comment: When testing with stop included in the code the div will slideDown just fine, but it refuses to move up again when the cancel button is pressed.

Comment: @Michelindoll Try again with the update of my answer

Comment: @Michelindoll The code in the fiddle (previous to your modifications based on this answer) should be in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Others have commented with `stopPropagation()`, but you can also not expand `#inputDiv` unless it's already visible, like so:

```
$(function(){
  $("#add").click(function () {
    if($("#inputDiv").css('display') == 'none'){
      $("#inputDiv").slideDown(1000);
    }
  });
  $("#cancel").click(function () {
    $("#inputDiv").slideUp(1000);
  });
});
```